# set label attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 4 labels as below:

```
<label id = "t1">Tag 1 </label>
<label id = "t2">Tag 2 </label>
<label id = "t3">Tag 3 </label>
<label id = "t4">Tag 4 </label>
```

I want to set one Tag as bold at one time. Lets say if i want to set "Tag 1" as bold then remaining should be normal font and if I set "Tag 2" as bold then remaining should be set to normal font.

What should be the code for jquery ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a class:

> W3C: The separation of HTML from CSS makes it easier to maintain sites, share style sheets across pages, and tailor pages to different environments. This is referred to as the separation of structure (or: content) from presentation.

```
.bold {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

```
$('label').click(function() {
   $('label').removeClass('bold')
   $(this).addClass('bold')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

A variation of @Raminson's

you can use a class:

```
.bold {
   font-weight: bold;
}

$('label').click(function() {
   $(this).addClass('bold').siblings('label').removeClass('bold');
})
```

Comment: @PranayRana , yes can be useful if he doesnt want to edit css file, but if its ok this should be a neat solution compared to injecting styles with jQuery, again a personal preference. Some performance gain also maybe.

Answer (score 0):

just do like this

for bold

```
$('#t1').css({ 'font-weight': 'bold' });
```

to remove bold

```
$('#t1').css({ 'font-weight': ''});
```

for each you need to do like this

```
function applyboldtolable(id)
{
$('label').each(function()
{
  $(this).css({ 'font-weight': ''});
});
   $('#'+id).css({ 'font-weight': 'bold' });

}
```

Note you can replace .each with

```
$('label').css({ 'font-weight': ''});
```

Comment: It will set only one tag as bold but remaining (if anyone already bold, will remain bold)

Comment: @fawad - check my function applyboldtolable which you can use for each lable control of your need

Comment: @AnkitGautam - yes there is no need to it but in case you want to do soemthing in that function with each lable...thats it nothing else you can remove if you dont need it..

Answer (score 0):

```
function setBoldLabel(labelID){
    $('label').each( function () {
                 if($(this).id()==labelID)
                 $(this).css({ 'font-weight': 'bold' });
                 else
                 $(this).css({ 'font-weight': 'normal' }); 
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the font weight on label click use below code

```
<label class="tlabel" id = "t1">Tag 1 </label>
<label class="tlabel" id = "t2">Tag 2 </label>
<label class="tlabel" id = "t3">Tag 3 </label>
<label class="tlabel" id = "t4">Tag 4 </label>

.bold {
   font-weight: bold;
}

$('.tlabel').click(function() {
   $('.tlabel').removeClass('bold')
   $(this).addClass('bold')
});
```